# Remove ssl from wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, http, ssl, https

I have one site which working on the WP and had a SSL certificate. I just removed my certificate (from my godaddy account) now it is bringing me an error when i trying to load the site.

[image]

I have removed the project and make one draft index.php file it works perfect. Its mean that problem in the wordpress.

Also when i am writing http://example.com it is redirecting me to https://example.com
I have checked the .htaccess file there are no rewrite rule like that.

Can any one say me how can i solve this problem.

Comment: You're probably going to have to update the `site_url` in your database.

Comment: i done it already from wp_optons table :( no any luck.

Comment: can you check if the redirection is from application or through apache, through any log file. In apache you can enable something like `LogLevel warn rewrite:trace4`

Comment: Try another browser? It could be cached in your browser.

Comment: It is same everywhere in every browser